# Record audio and store to root directory

Tags: android, io

I need to implement next functionality. I want to store audio mp3 file in root (or somewhere else) then **get it back** and send via e-mail like attachment. I've set output file like follow:

```
recorder.setOutputFile(getFilesDir().getPath() + fileName + ".mp3");
```

But I don't know how to get it back or even just see it. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
File dir = new File(path);
String[] files = dir.list();
```

path = your path of the storage.